# White screen with pointer after removing Unity

Tags: 10.10, gnome, unity

I have the same problem . I am a newbie. I added the repository with

> sudo add apt-get-repository ppa:canonical-dx-team/une

then i went to ubuntu software center and installed "unity interface of ubuntu netbook edition" . after installing i found a problem with User interface as it kept on flashing
when mouse points to side panel . so i decided to remove it . I removed it form Ubuntu software center . there were other unity related apps installed , but i did not remove then
as i had no idea what they were about . Now i ended up with a blank white screen with mouse pointer whenever i login. though i m able to login using gdm , but the screen is blank white.
I tried to these commands also

> sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell
>
> sudo apt-get remove unity
>
> sudo restart gdm

but they did not work at all
i also tried

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

it too did not work.
Note:I donot have any sort of graphics card or video card on my pc

please help !!!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you still have some leftovers on your computer that are trying to run Unity. If you do have a file called `/usr/share/xsessions/une.desktop`, then this should bring you back to your normal GNOME session:

When at the GDM login screen, make sure you have set the session to "Ubuntu Desktop Edition":

[image]

Now if that worked, you still have some packages from the Netbook Editions installed. To get rid of (most of) them, execute the following in a gnome-terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge appmenu-gtk bamfdaemon indicator-appmenu \
indicator-datetime libbamf0 libclutk-0.3-0 libdee-1.0-0 \
libmutter-private0 libunity-misc0 libunity0 mutter mutter-common \
ubuntu-netbook-default-settings unity unity-asset-pool \
unity-place-applications unity-place-files
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @htorque .selecting desired session and login really worked and the file /usr/share/xsessions/une.desktop was there which i removed after uninstalling all unity leftovers.Now its working fine.

Comment: @Sameer Pandit If this answer solved your problem, click on the checkmark and the up arrow.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove unity    
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-shell   
sudo shutdown -r now
```